# Registering ECS services in CloudMap in Multi-Region environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-regions, aws-cloudmap

AWS ECS allows for new services to automatically use Service Discovery, as mentioned in the documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-configure-servicediscovery.html

If I understand correctly, there should always be a namespace and a service created in CloudMap, before a service instance can register itself into it. After registering, the service instance can then be discovered using DNS records, which are kept in Route 53, which is a global service. The namespace has its own private zone and applications from VPCs associated with this zone can query the records and discover the service needed, regardless of the region they are in.

However, if I understand Correctly, CloudMap resources themselves are regional

Let's consider the following scenario: There is a CloudMap namespace and service X defined in region A. For redundancy reasons I would like instances of service X run in region A, but also in region B. However, when configuring service discovery in ECS, it is not possible to use a namespace from region A.

How can then CloudMap service discovery be used in a multi-region environment? Shall corresponding namespaces be created in both regions?

Answer (score 3):

Redundancy can be built in within a single region. I have not seen a regulator yet that expects more than what is offered by multiple Availability Zones in a single region, but if you still wanted to achieve what you are asking, you would need to perform some kind of VPC network peering: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/peering-scenarios.html#peering-scenarios-full

I've not got experience with how Cloud Map behaves in this context though. Assuming DNS resolution is possible, it would supposedly still work. But aws services are best (cheaper, more stable and lower latency) when used within each region, targeting their region specific api https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/cloud_map.html